# When and how are thread_local variables initialized and destroyed?

Tags: c++, destructor, thread-local

I'd like to better understand `thread_local` before I use it in my code.

Let's say, I declare

```
thread_local myclass value;
```

That will create new instance of `myclass` for each thread that is using the `value`? What happens when the thread exits? Will the instance be freed or is it going to remain somewhere in the memory? When will be called the destructor?

Does `thread_local` lock the constructor so that only one can be called at any moment in time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **[basic.stc.thread]/1** All variables declared with the `thread_local` keyword have *thread storage duration*. The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the thread in which they are created. There is a distinct object or reference per thread, and use of the declared name refers to the entity associated with the current thread.
>
> **[basic.stc.thread]/2** A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use (6.2) and, if constructed, shall be destroyed on thread exit.

No, there is no automatic synchronization for the constructor call. None is needed, as only one thread can possibly attempt to construct a given thread-local object.

Comment: Let's say I declare random number generator thread_local, and it takes it's seed from time. If initialization is not synchronized, for this scenario we can have several random number generators returning same sequences of numbers

Comment: That may happen even if initialization were synchronized (which it isn't, but let's pretend). All that's needed is that two calls occur within the same second. If that's a problem in your program, you need to arrange for a better seeding mechanism; thread synchronization got nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: You can often use `random_device` to seed your prng: `thread_local std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());`

Answer (score 4):

According to [this storage duration reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) a `thread_local` variable:

> ... is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends.

So yes, when the thread ends the life-time of `thread_local` variables for that thread also ends, which means those specific instances will be destructed.